# Come si dice "Shut up, and get in the cart" as a strict command with the "lei" form, not "tu"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

Come si dice "Shut up, and get in the cart" as a command with the *lei* form, not *tu*? 
I want to convey a strict command to GET IN THE CART, like a parent might do with emphasis, as a last resort, and in a very imperative sense. (But, I want the more formal *Lei* forms, not the *tu* form.) I can't find the right verb, they all seem to miss the mark.

I have considered;
**1** *Zitto e ottenere nel carrello*  (wrong verb meaning ~ used more to
  indicate an achievement or goal?
**2** *Zitto, e si mettersi nel carrello* (Put yourself into the cart?) My choice, so far... 
**3** *Zitto, e entra nel carrello.*  (Too polite, not enough emphasis?)

Comment: Some context would help. In particular, what kind of cart are we talking about? Note that "ottenere nel carrello" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Okay - context.  We are golfers and are planning a trip to Italy this year.  This is a traditional insult among our group. It sounds awful, but it cracks us up.  In golf, you have to keep moving, and if someone gets long-winded we say "Shut up, and get in the cart!" ...   I think you have to be there to think it is funny, but I am studying Italian, and this is a must have phrase for me! ;-)

Comment: You can't use the word "carrello" as a translation of golf cart. Beyond the three options (golf cart, golf buggy and golf car) given by Wikipedia at https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_cart, I suggest also "auto da golf" and "macchina da golf" (or simply "auto" and "macchina") as translations.

Comment: Given the context and meaning (teasingly saying "hurry up" by inviting someone to get in a metaphorical cart), I'd be inclined to dismiss it as untranslatable in its literal form anyway. and I would suggest finding out what Italian golf players actually say in such situations.
That said, if I were to invite someone - in a playful manner - to shut up and get in an *actual* golf cart I'd really just go with "zitto e sali" (1st person) or "stia zitto e salga" (3rd person).
As a native speaker I would not add "salga in macchina" except maybe the first time.

Comment: Hmmm...  Well, we ARE talking about an actual golf cart, not a metaphorical one, BUT - to translate it, I need a short snappy word that is understandable.  Would not carrello, while not perfect be sort of a slangy thing to say? (It sort of would compare the golf cart to a farm wagon, or something)

Comment: So, wait, you are saying dispense with "the cart" part completely and  just say "Zitto e sali"....    Maybe! ;-)

Comment: @Msfolly No, that I know of, unless it's golfer slang, "carrello" just has nothing to do with a golf cart. And yes, I'd just say "zitto e sali/salga" :)

Comment: "Zitto e sali/salga" is the best form IMHO as well. Plus, it's quick, snaps back at them, and it's easy to memorize :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's take it by parts:

a) If one wishes to say "shut up" in the sense that someone is being annoying (by getting to the hole in less strokes, say ;-), the word "taci" is used, as in "**Taci** e bevi un po' di vino!" which means "**Shut up** and have a little wine!"

b) The imperative "get in" would be "salga in" as in "**Salga in** macchina!" which means "**Get in** the car!"

c) The phrase **golf cart** is simply used in Italian as it is.

So, **Taci e salga in golf cart!** would seem to be closest in meaning and intent to **Shut up and get in the golf cart!**

Comment: I like that.  I have continued to research this, and yes, I have found that the the word golf cart seems to be unchanged from English to Italian.  Your example, "Taci e bevi un po' di vino."  seems to have just the right tone to it, and captures exactly, I think, the mood of playful, yet affectionate dismissiveness.  Since Americans often shorten references to things while in a playful mood, I would shorten it to cart, as well, instead of golf cart.

Comment: One question, though...  I looked up tacere, and a lot of the translations I found have to do with the Bible.  (Hold thy peace, fall silent, etc.)  Would you say that the imperative of tacere is generally believed to be more polite than zitto?  (I could not find a verb for zitto, so I assume it is a noun?  I also found this… http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5380/taci-sta-zitto-ways-to-say-shut-up-be-quiet-hush

Comment: Non sarebbe "taci e sali" oppure "taccia e salga"?

Comment: That is, with the "lei" form, shouldn't it be "taccia" instead of "taci"?

Comment: Can I just say that "sali in golf cart" is VERY weird-sounding to me? How about "*sul* cart"?

Comment: I find *Taci* to be a little formal, and very rarely used in everyday speech. Then again, perhaps this is exactly the quality the OP intends to give his sentence.

Comment: I agree about “in golf cart” sounding slightly off.

Answer (score 12):

I'd say *Stia zitto e salga sul carrello*.

*Stia* e *salga* are in the subjunctive, third-person form used in formal phrasing (the corresponding *tu*-form would be *Stai zitto e sali sul carrello*, in the imperative mood).

<sup>As for your attempts:</sup>


<sup>- *ottenere* means “to get” in such contexts as “I got a great result”;</sup>


<sup>- *si mettersi* isn't correct; *Zitto e si metta nel carrello* would be acceptable;</sup>


<sup>- *Zitto, e entra nel carrello* would be acceptable (and quite brusque) for the *tu*-form; the corresponding *lei*-form would be *Zitto, e entri nel carrello*.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, also, for the corrections and the alternatives... I am SO new, and have so much to learn.  Having a few fun things to say means a lot.  (Also, I just studying on my own)

Answer (score 4):

The following four options are literal translations of the given sentence; the differences between them concern the tone of the speech and cover some possible relations between the speaker and the listeners (how friendly/funny/sarcastic you want to be).
In brackets there is the corresponding plural version, used if the speech is addressed to more than one listener.

**Option 1**

> Zitto e in macchina! (Zitti e in macchina!)

This is direct and gives emphasis, but if said with a half-smile face, it should be funny. Note that this can be used in both informal and formal speeches, due to the absence of verbs.

**Option 2**

> Stia zitto e salga in macchina. (State zitti e salite in macchina.)

Probably the closest translation to the English sentence. It is as formal and strict as required, but also hides some fun behind it.

**Option 3**

> Faccia silenzio e salga in macchina. (Fate silenzio e salite in macchina.)

The expression "fare silenzio" is a synonym of "stare zitto", but usually it is felt to be less rude. In a standard formal speech, one tries to avoid to say "stare zitto", because it sounds inappropriate.

**Option 4**

> Le impongo di fare silenzio e di salire in macchina. (Vi impongo di fare silenzio e di salire in macchina.)

This version is usually said with sarcasm, imitating (and making fun) of some excessively formal, snooty and full of deference speeches.

**Other options**

If the translation needs not to be 100% literal, I would suggest also:

- Poche chiacchiere e si sbrighi (Poche chiacchiere e sbrigatevi);
- Chiuda il becco e allunghi il passo (Chiudete il becco e allungate il passo).

Comment: Ah!  I just saw these.  I like that you gave me so many options - I have a lot to consider, now.  Option 4 is very interesting...  I also think the Chiuda il becco and Poche chiacchiere show great imagination, and might add the snappiness  am looking for.  I am going to practice saying them to see how they SOUND.

Answer (score 2):

Some expressions and jokes can lose all their wittiness and power when ported from a language to another. If the expression is intended to be directed to English speaking people that are familiar with it and the translation is to add another level of fun by saying it in the language of the country you are in, then you can go on and say "*Stia zitto e salga sul golf cart*", or simply "Stia zitto e salga" like others suggested, your friends would understand the point. But if you try to use that sentence with an Italian person that is not familiar with the English correspondent you would simply end with a case of "lost in translation", so I'm with Tobia Tesan in suggesting to find a sentence Italian golfers use, there might be none. Be careful your meaning is really clear when using sentences like some of the alternatives suggested in other posts, you could sound really rude if the person didn't get the point of it. For example "*chiuda il becco*" would be like saying "*shut your piehole*", which isn't the best thing to say to someone in most of the situations.
The word *cart*, as per *buggy*, in Italian is translated as *carrozzino* o *calesse*, more elegant and refined than a *carro* that would mean a wagon/farm cart to haul materials, we don't use any of these names for a golf cart, we keep the English name. "*Get in*", with the Lei form, is translated as "*salga*" o "entri" (where to get in doesn't follow it since that's usually clear from the context).

Comment: That is a very clear explanation, thank you!